# Why don't I get code-completion in Flask/SQLAlchemy?

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, flask-sqlalchemy

Visual Studio Code seems to be able to recognize the return type of connect() (s. screenshot) but is not able to provide autocompletion for the *conn* object below.

Any suggestions?

I'm using Flask, SQLAlchemy, as well as Flask-SQLAlchemy.

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yfn4R.png)

Comment: I assume you've installed the pylance extension?

Comment: I have. Does it cause the problem?

Comment: No problem, just that's what would be providing the completion features

Comment: It will lose the variable type when you use `as` keywords.

Comment: Can I do something about this?

Comment: What Steven is saying is not strictly right for me, if I don't use with/as and just open a connection using 'conn = engine.connection()', completion does not work for variable conn neither.

Answer (score 1):

I'm facing the same problem using just SqlAlchemy without Flask.

Python 3.10.7
SqlAlchemy 1.4.41

I read somewhere else, not sure now exactly where, that is recommended to change the python linter to flake8, so I did it.

It is working partially for me now, some objects like **engine** work ok, but not connection or result.

In case it is useful for you, if you have a virtual enviroment set
just go into VSCODE Ctrl-Shift-P  and choose "Select Linter" and select flake8.

Just starting with Python myself, so not to much more help I can give you, but some people mentioned this solved their issue, not for me.

**UPDATE**

Looking through the code I found engine.connect() returned something like a _future.Connection, my code was

```
engine = create_engine(pg_connection_string, echo=True, future=True)

# Test connection
with engine.connect() as conn:
    result = conn.execute(text("select now()"))
    print(result.all())
```

From what I read in sqlAlchemy docs, this has to do with being prepared for version 2.0 (but really no sure), so I replaced future=True with future=False, and now completion seems to work ok.

Hope it helps